# Heredoc and closing tags issue

Tags: php

case 1:

```
<?php    
echo <<<"FOOBAR"
Hello World!
FOOBAR;
```

versus

case 2:

```
<?php
echo <<<"FOOBAR"
Hello World!
FOOBAR;
?>
```

I have a question about heredoc usage.
I find some weird behavior for which I could use an explanation.

When I try case 1, I do not get the "Hello World!" output printed.
Instead I see the following parse error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 5
```

However, in case 2, I see it print correctly the text "Hello World!"

This is also true when I remove the closing tag in case 2 and just add an extra line instead.

Can anybody explain the behavior and why it happens?

Comment: I tried both of your examples, and they both function by echoing "Hello World!" as expected. I'm not sure why you're receiving an error in Case 1 because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: btw i am trying this in a windows environment using xampp if that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right

check Explanation:-
 It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

**It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.**

*If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line*.

for more check
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc